# Storing API object data in Hive Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I've got data coming in to my Flutter app from a Rest API, the structure of the API data is below;

[image]

Is there a way i can add this to a Hive box and be able to retrieve the data to use within my application?  I want to be able to find the points of service node that are attached to the main deliveryAddressNo.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: yes firstly try too create a model for the api response and register the model adapter with hive and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks @TomiwaIdowu, is it really that simple?  Do you have any examples i can take a look at for my exact issues? Thanks again!

Comment: As @Tomiwa Idowu said you have to create a model and its adapter for the data. Then you map all the incoming data into that model for you to get a list. Then you do ```HIve.box('box').get('data').putAll()```. Follow this to get an idea

Comment: Thanks @Samuel but i'm just not getting it.  I've created a model, an adapter but your line of code to help me out just doesn't work.  I assume i've to put my json response to a map to then enable me to Put it to my Hive box?